# Exclude nulls from ThenInclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have EF context as below

```
_context.Offices
       .Where( x => x.ID == id )
            .Include( x => x.County)
               .ThenInclude( x => x.Employees)
                    .ThenInclude( s => s.Department)
                        .ThenInclude( m => m.DeptUser )
            .Include( x => x.XYZ);
```

My problem is that DeptUser can be null. How do I exclude null items?

Comment: Did you try `.Where(o => o.County.Employees.Department.DeptUser != null)`?

Comment: No... where should I put this? within ThenInclude( m => m.DeptUser )?

Comment: Chain to the first `Where`: `Where(x => x.Id = id).Where(o => o.County.Employees......)`

Comment: But what happens if Employees or department is null? And the above does not remove nulls from lower Includes

Comment: You can chain it down after the last `.ThenInclude()` I believe. I think that would give you what you are asking for. It might do the same thing that @Fabio suggested though.